# Very weird error in common lisp

Tags: function, command-line, common-lisp

This is really giving me a headache

I have a following simple function written in a file.

```
 (defun find-num (string)
   (if (> (length string) 1)
       (parse-integer (remove (coerce (get-first-letter string)
                                      'character)
                              string))
     ;else
     1))
```

What it does is parse the number from string "a23" after removing the first letter.
I assumed that only the first char is a *letter* and the rest are "numbers".

I load the file, and when I try to run the function, it give me the error, saying:
**A proper list must not end with "a3" ... WHAT???**

But when I copy and paste the same exact code directly in the command line, the function works as it should be.

What is this ? Common lisp error ? Or is there something I am not seeing ?

```
 ;; Loading file C:\Users ... (hidden)
 ;; Loaded file C:\Users ... (hidden)
 T
 [2]> (find-num "a3")

 *** - ENDP: A proper list must not end with "a3"
 The following restarts are available:
 ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
 Break 1 [3]> :a

 [4]> (defun find-num (string)
   (if (> (length string) 1)
  (coerce (get-first-letter string) 'character) string))

     ;else
     1))
 WARNING: DEFUN/DEFMACRO: redefining function FIND-NUM in top-level, was
     defined in C:\Users\.... (hidden)
 FIND-NUM
 [5]> (find-num "a3")
 3 ;
 1
```

Comment: I also found that some other functions are also behaving similarly.

Comment: I copied your function into a file, replaced (get-first-letter string) with (aref string 0), loaded the file and it works.

Comment: I do the same as @RainerJoswig, it also works.

Comment: @wvxvw haha you are absolutely correct. I feel like idiot now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Btw.:

```
(parse-integer (remove (coerce (get-first-letter string)
                               'character)
                       string))
```

is just

```
(parse-integer (remove (aref string 0) string))
```

is better:

```
(parse-integer (subseq string 1))
```

is best

```
(parse-integer string :start 1)
```

Comment: It's very nice to see the refactor process.

Comment: That is so much cleaner. Can't believe I never found any of those useful built-in functions rather than implementing my own functions in a tedious way.

Comment: Wouldn’t the (aref string 1) actually be (aref string 0) for returning the first letter?